# DB schema to store different types of places in a city

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I have to store all **places** of city in database. As places are different like schools, colleges, university, hospital, hostel, hotel, shop, fast foods, bus station, banks etc

I cannot store them in one table because they have different attributes and also categories are unknown, and catagories may be added later at run time. So we cannot fix attributes.

How to solve this problem?  please help.

Comment: Read Chapter 12 of Enterprise Model Patterns by David Hay. That chapter is on Facilities and modeling them in databases. You can get the book on Safari for $12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is pretty vague, and @Jamie is absolutely right in his pessimism.  You should find yourself a consultant to help you.

That said...

You can make separate tables for each entity (*school*, *college*, etc).  Note that they all share some basic characteristics (they have a 'name', an 'address', etc).  You can put those in a different table, which should simplify things, so:

```
 place (id, name, address, city, state, zip)
 school (place_id, principals_name)
 college (place_id, is_accredited)
```

This makes it easier to add attributes to any given place (as you won't have one large table to ALTER).  Note that I said *easier*, not *easy*.

Many people will add generic columns like 'data1', 'data2', but I've always found that to be confusing and difficult to maintain.

Please go find a consultant...  Free advice is worth exactly what you pay for it...

Comment: but what? if user want to add another catagory from front end like he wants to add private academy and we have not created table in db for that

Comment: Users don't usually administer databases.  To me, "private academy" would be a column in many of the secondary tables (both 'school' and 'college' could be private, where a 'restaurant' might not be).